# How do I print the values as well as count in Thymeleaf from a JPA custom query?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
@Query(value = "select p.*, count(c.post_id) from posts as p join comments as c on p.id = c.post_id group by c.post_id order by p.id desc", nativeQuery = true)
List<Post> findAllAndCountResponsesOrderByPostIdDesc();
```

I have this as my custom query in my repository. I know the SQL works because I tested in out in MySQL, but I just can't seem to print it out in my Thymeleaf template. In my controller, I've added a model attribute, 'posts' for example, and if I call all of the table columns, it works (post.title, post.body, etc...), but when I try to print out the count (post.count), it breaks. What would I need to put to print it out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate what "it breaks" exactly means? Is `Post` your entity that you persist? If so does it have a property in Java to put the number of comments?

Comment: Give the `count(c.post_id)` a SQL column alias, for example: `count(c.post_id) as post_count`, and use the alias in your Thymeleaf template: `${post.post_count}`. Without this alias, I think MySQL will generate a column name for you - which is not `count`. but probably `count(c.post_id)` - i.e. the full expression.

Comment: I was able to get the number by calling our `${posts.comment.size()}`. I didn't know that with the join in the table, it would allow me to call the other object as well...